# What is the earliest Vulgate text with easily accessible scans on the internet?

Tags: latin-vulgate

I was looking for scans of Vulgate manuscripts for another question, but they were hard to find. What is the earliest text with scans which are easily accessible on the internet?

Answer (score 3):

There are some earlier manuscripts of the Vulgate that are viewable online:

The **[Book of Kells](http://digitalcollections.tcd.ie/home/index.php?DRIS_ID=MS58_003v)** and the **[Book of Mulling](http://digitalcollections.tcd.ie/home/index.php?folder_id=1648&pidtopage=MS60_001&entry_point=1)** can both be viewed on Digital Collections.tcd.ie

Comment: Excellent, thank you, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

[Gutenberg digital](http://www.gutenbergdigital.de/) has [*The Göttingen Gutenberg Bible*](http://www.gutenbergdigital.de/gudi/eframes/index.htm), which was printed in 1454. The [The British Library](http://www.bl.uk/) has two copies of [Johann Gutenberg’s Bible](http://molcat1.bl.uk/treasures/gutenberg/search.asp). And [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/) has [*1462 The Gutenberg Bible Latin Vulgate*](https://archive.org/details/1462TheGutenbergBibleLatinVulgate).

<sub>[image: new] **UPDATE**</sub>
[Gallica](http://gallica.bnf.fr/blog/recherche/?query=330) has two copies (ca. 1455) of [four (printed on parchment)](http://gallica.bnf.fr/services/engine/search/sru?operation=searchRetrieve&version=1.2&collapsing=disabled&rk=21459;2&query=%28gallica%20all%20%22bible%20de%20gutenberg%201455%20v%C3%A9lin%22%29%20and%20dc.relation%20all%20%22cb35951126v%22) and [two (printed on paper)](http://gallica.bnf.fr/services/engine/search/sru?operation=searchRetrieve&version=1.2&collapsing=disabled&rk=21459;2&query=%28gallica%20all%20%22bible%20de%20gutenberg%201455%20papier%22%29%20and%20dc.relation%20all%20%22cb35951126v%22) volumes, respectively.

Comment: That's certainly a baseline, though I'm hoping someone will know of an earlier one.

Comment: @curiousdannii. I believe the Vatican library has now put all its manuscripts on line.

Comment: https://digi.vatlib.it/